# Open Source iPhone app UI Controls?

Tags: iphone, ios, open-source

I am quit new to iPhone development, developing an which **need controls somethings like in the image below**. I searched for this in almost every new network which have open source controls, but no luck. So here are 3 question:

1. **Any open source library for these controls that are used in below image?**
2. If no idea about any open source control like this, then how do I have to start developing this controls by writing hard code? any helping libraries for his job?

   Here is url to this: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/circle-whos-around-you/id488720081?mt=8

   Every Single clue would be helpful, please share any information you think would be useful.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [AwesomeMenu](https://github.com/levey/AwesomeMenu). I am sure this will help you to create the same custom control.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a lot of custom Controls for iOS from the below Link

Check out http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls

Comment: already checked there, no luck here!!!

Answer (score 2):

You want to create animation like when user click on friends button it open friend list in animation. if you want like that then please check out this example https://github.com/levey/AwesomeMenu and http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/aurosetteview and http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/quadcurvemenu

Answer (score 1):

You can check here, i hope it's help you

http://code4app.net

another one

http://code4app.com